# Why is this nested promise.then executed before the promise's method?

Tags: node.js, promise

I am trying to use promises to call getLoginState and then store that value so I can use it later.

I am wondering why in the following codeblock, the .then inside of q.fcall(getLoginState) is called before the getLoginState method?

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var q = require('q');

var login = "tyler";
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    port: '3306',
    database: 'root'
});

var gotLoginState;
var state;

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if(err != null){
        console.log("connection err: "+err);
    }

    q.nfcall(connection.query.bind(connection),"SELECT id, password, salt, gender, banned, gm, pin, pic, characterslots, tos FROM accounts WHERE name = ?",[login])
        .then(function (results) {
          console.log("select: "+results[0][0]);
//        }).then(q.fcall(getLoginState), function () {
            q.fcall(getLoginState)
                .then(function() {
                    console.log("gotLoginState: " + state);
                }).catch(function (error){
                   console.log("error in inner thing");
            }).done();
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.error("promise error: "+error);
        })
        .done();
});

var accId = 1;
var getLoginState = function() {
    q.nfcall(connection.query.bind(connection), "SELECT loggedin, lastlogin, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(birthday) as birthday FROM accounts WHERE id = ?", [accId])
        .then(function (results) {
            state = results[0][0].loggedin;
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log("error in chaining: "+error);
        }).done();
};
```

Comment: One thing to be careful of (I can't tell if this is actually a problem in your code or not) is that you're potentially referencing `getLoginState` before you've assigned it a value.  That's one reason why I don't use the `var getLoginState = function() {` form of defining a function unless it is required.  If you use `function getLoginState() {` instead, it will be hoisted and always defined before you can use it.

Comment: @jfriend00 promises are guaranteed to execute in some future time on the async loop and never synchronously - so it is not a problem in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flow control in promises works like in synchronous code:

- To return you use the `return` keyword.
- To signal an error you use t he `throw` keyword.

The way promises work - is by waiting for them. `nfcall` is called on a NodeJS style "errback" callback. In order for your code to work you need to **return from getLoginState**, and then not use `nfcall` since the method already returns a promise:

```
var getLoginState = function() { // this should be nodeify probably
    return q.nfcall(...) // note the `return` statement here
        .then(function (results) {
            state = results[0][0].loggedin; // do not mutate state like this
        }).catch(function (error) {         // instead use return values
            console.log("error in chaining: "+error); // don't suppress errors
                                                      // logging is not enough
        }); // don't do `.done` if you want to chain to it
};
```

And then in the above part:

```
// don't use the `.connect` callback, promisify it
q.nfcall(...) // promisify that method _once_ in your real code
.then(function (results) {
   console.log("select: "+results[0][0]); // why just the log?
   return getLoginState() // note this is a regular function call
            .then(function() { // also note the `return`
                console.log("gotLoginState: " + state);
            }).catch(function (error){
               console.log("error in inner thing");
    }); // no done here, since we chain to it
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.error("promise error: "+error);
}).done(); // you only need one `.done` at the end, and only in old
           // promise libraries
```

I'd like to emphasize that this could could be written better, there is no good reason to nest here rather than chain, and the connecting should be done in a promise - the above code is just the closest thing to your code that works.

Comment: awesome! Thanks so much :) I tried writing this better without nesting:  q.nfcall(...)
        .then(function (results) {
            console.log("select: "+results[0][0]);
        }).then(return getLoginState(), function (state) {
                console.log("gotLoginState: " + state);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.error("promise error: "+error);
        }).done();